# how can I know the element is the last item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

for example,we have

```
<ul><li></li><li></li>....</ul>
```

we don't know how many li tag in these code and right now i have a reference to one of these li elements.
is there a simple way to know if this reference is the last item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) selector, and check if the element matches it:

```
if( $('li').is(':last-child') ) {
    // ...
}
```

You should replace the `'li'` selector above with your reference to the element.

Note that replacing it is necessary, since [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) will return true if *any* of the elements in the matched set matches the new selector, so you really only want to call it on your specific list-item.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
   if($(this).is(':last-child')) { 
      // I am the youngest!
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient is to have a `last` class assigned to it when it's rendered on the server.

This way, a simple, cheap and efficient `$( this ).hasClass( 'last' )` will be enough.

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
if ( $( this ).hasClass( 'last' ) ) { // cheap
}
```

<sub>Remember: most of the time to render a page is spent on the client, the more efficient you are, the better.</sub>

Comment: Just clarifying, but aren't these calls equally expensive? The last-child selector is native to css, so it should be pretty efficient (I don't think it has to loop, but I could be wrong). Calling `.hasClass()` should have just as much overhead as `.is()`, plus it saves the server (i.e. shared processor) some work. Just a thought, let me know if I'm way off

Comment: @nbrooks usually, 80% of the time is spent rendering on the client, the server is often cool enough :-). `hasClass` is a simple check on the `className` property of the object (or using `classList` if available), while `QSA`, which may be fast, still has to select.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).is(':last-child'));
});
```